# Add space before reading an input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python program which works as a calculator.

```py
import re


value = 0
run = True

while run:
    if value == 0:
        equation = input('Enter the equation ')
    else:
        equation=input(str(value))
        # print(equation + ' ')
    if equation == 'quit':
            run = False
    else:
        equation = re.sub("[a-zA-Z""]",'',equation)
        if value ==0:
            # equation=eval(equation)
            value=eval(equation)
        else:
            value=eval(str(value)+equation)
            print(equation + ' ')
```

The program works without problem , but when reading the input after the first iteration , the terminal is as below

```sh
python3 file.py
Enter the equation 10+10
20+30
```

The next input can be provided next to 20. I want to add a space before reading the input , so the output will be as shown below

```sh
python3 file.py
Enter the equation 10+10
20 +30
```

How can I add a space before reading the next input so the cursor will create a space

Example

```py
input=input('Enter the input ')
```

Python Version : 3.7.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply append a space to the string given to `input`.

In your example, changing the line `equation=input(str(value))` to `equation=input(str(value) + ' ')` will produce your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, this line is not what you want:

```
equation=input(str(value))
```

Outputting the result of the calculation should be separate from the next input because of semantics. The argument to `input()` is the prompt to tell the user what to do. "20" (or whatever intermediate result) is not a good instruction for the user.

So the code becomes

```
print(value, end=" ")    # end=" " prevents a newline and adds a space instead
equation=input()         # don't give any prompt, if there's no need to
```